# Dev tools showing wrong line number of sass files

Tags: google-chrome, sass, google-chrome-devtools

I've recently switched from firefox (memory usage went astronomical (2gb+) every now and than) to chrome. I'm using sass for my CSS and strange thing is happening to me. Sometimes, when I add new rules into a scss file, dev tools starts showing wrong files and/or wrong line numbers for those (and only those) newly added rules. The wierd thing is, that if I reset chrome settings to default, the problem disappears. I havent changed any unusual settings, I even tried not to change any settings after the settings reset, and it's still happening. It might happend once a day or twice a hour, didn't really find anything to get me closer to the reason.

Did anybody experience this issue? Maybe found a solution?